# Can I return a message from a python git pre-receive hook prefixed error: instead of remote:

Tags: python, git, hook

I have written a git pre-receive hook in python to abort the process if a user tries to push to a prohibited directory.

The function that does this takes a parameter of filepaths and iterates over them looking for the naughty dir, like this;

```
for filename in changed:
    pieces = filename.split('/')
    if(len(pieces) >3 and pieces[0] == 'application' and pieces[1] == 'modules' and pieces[3] == 'core'):
        # User is trying to push to application/modules/[MODULE_NAME]/core directory, they must be stopped!
        msg = 'You are pushing code that will be over-written by framework updates: ' + filename + '. THIS IS NOT ALLOWED!'
        print(msg)
        exit(1)
```

This works, and returns a message formatted like this;

*remote: You are pushing code that will be overwritten..etc.*

Which is followed by

*error: failed to push some refs...etc.*

What I would like to do however, is replace the print call and return the message as an error instead, so it reads;

*error: You are pushing code will be overwritten...etc.*

My reasoning is that I suspect different gui git clients will present errors differently (i.e. in red, with a pop-up, exclamation marks etc.) and they are more likely to be read by the person trying to push. Does anyone know how to do this please?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, as git's hook handling code simply takes every string that comes back (on sideband channel 2, specifically; that's where hook output winds up) and sticks the word `remote:` in front of it (see `recv_sideband()` in `sideband.c`).  You could get it to print `remote: error:` and cross fingers that the gui will recognize that as an error string, perhaps. :-)

Comment: That's a shame. I can't return an exception or anything like that then, like I would from a web service?

Comment: The code I described is for the native git protocol (used over git:// and ssh:// connections).  The web interface is slightly different, but winds up doing pretty much the same thing I think (I have much less experience with it).